# How to use AWS S3, copy file from one bucket to another and get the url back to store in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, sdk, carrierwave, fog

I am using Ruby on Rails AWS SDK to copy files from one bucket to another and store the url in carrierwave. The app uses carrierwave and I need to store the new copied url to the database field that carrierwave uses.  The problem is the url is private so I tried to just generate the url and store it in remote_file_url but it can't access the file.  The files are very large so I can't use carrierwave to upload the file to sdk. I tried and had no success.

obj.public_url did not work for me.  When I copied the file it worked but not when moved it from one bucket to another.
Here is what I have:

```
picture_name = "my_picture.jpg"
@picture     = Picture.find(id)
upload_dir   = "uploads/picture/file/#{@picture.id}/my_picture.jpg"

s3 = Fog::Storage.new(provider: 'AWS',  :aws_access_key_id      => access_key, :aws_secret_access_key  => secret_access_key ,:region => region)

obj =  s3.copy_object('my-temp-bucket',
               picture_name,
               "my-target-bucket",
               upload_dir, acl: 'public-read')   

@picture.remote_image_url = obj.url_for(:read, :expires => 10*60)
@picture.save
```

I also tried with no luck.

```
@picture.remote_image_url = obj.public_url 
@picture.save
```

I get an error  undefined method `bucket' for #

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: I'm seeing a typo: `obj.url_for(:read, :expires => 10*60)`

Comment: Are the files already uploaded to `my-temp-bucket` and you are trying to copy them to `my-target-bucket`? Since files are copied with `public-read`, you should be able to use `public_url()`